# SQLAlchemy subquery - average of sums

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

is there any way how to write the following SQL statement in SQLAlchemy ORM:

```
SELECT AVG(a1) FROM (SELECT sum(irterm.n) AS a1 FROM irterm GROUP BY irterm.item_id);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
sums = session.query(func.sum(Irterm.n).label('a1')).group_by(Irterm.item_id).subquery()
average = session.query(func.avg(sums.c.a1)).scalar()
```

Comment: Why are you writing in the query sums.c.a1 instead of sums.a1? I don't know what's the effect

Comment: @Guido `sums` is a subquery object, not a mapped class. It exposes its available columns through the `c` and `columns` attributes.