# return average of counts of records after a group by statement

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a bunch of records for which I want to compute the average count for over certain time units (hours, days, weeks). So one situation would be that I want to calculate an average number of records that I have per day in a given range. To be more clear, this would just be a single number.

The way I'm doing it right now (which obviously does not work because it doesn't take the average), is the following sqlalchemy query:

```
db.query(MyClass).filter(MyClass.created.between(start_date, end_date)).group_by(func.HOUR(MyClass.created)).count()
```

Here's the output to `SHOW CREATE TABLE yt_video`:

```
| yt_video | CREATE TABLE `yt_video` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `published_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `yt_data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

All I really care about is the created timestamp, but hope this helps.

Comment: Please provide sample data and table schema.

Comment: You could use numpy.average or you can take your result, sum up all the values and divide by the count of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2273845/4054923).

In your case, using the table definition provided:

```
from sqlalchemy import cast, func
from sqlalchemy.types import TIME, DATE
from sqlalchemy.sql import between

time_from = ...  # get filter time maybe using datetime.time()
time_to = ...  # idem
counts = session.query(func.count('*').label('count')).\
    filter(between(cast(MyClass.created, TIME),
           time_from,
           time_to)).\
    group_by(cast(MyClass.created, DATE))

avg = session.query(func.avg(counts.subquery().columns.count)).scalar()

print avg
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a curiosity, in MySQL 8 and up you can use window functions to the same effect:

```
# limit(1) should work as well instead of distinct, because we know that all rows
# contain the exact same result.
db.query(func.avg(func.count()).over()).\
    filter(MyClass.created.between(start_date, end_date)).\
    group_by(func.date(MyClass.created)).\
    distinct().\
    scalar()
```

This works because logically window functions are evaluated after GROUP BY has produced the group rows.