# How to take avg on count using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, database, orm, sqlalchemy

How do I take avg on count in SQLAlchemy?
I tried a lot of things, but all of them failed.
Code:

```py
month = sqlalchemy.func.date_trunc('month', Complaint.date)
records_count = sqlalchemy.sql.func.count(ClientGroupRecord.id)
complained_clients = session.query(Friend, records_count.label('count'), month). \
    filter(Friend.friend_id == friend_id). \
    join(Complaint, Complaint.friend == Friend.friend_id). \
    join(ClientGroup, Complaint.client_group == ClientGroup.client_group_id). \
    join(ClientGroupRecord, ClientGroup.client_group_id == ClientGroupRecord.client_group_id). \
    join(Client, Client.client_id == ClientGroupRecord.client_id). \
    group_by(month, Friend.friend_id)

records_avg = sqlalchemy.sql.func.avg(records_count)

result = ???
```

In a `result` I don't need `Friend`, but want `avg` on the column, which is labeled `count` grouped by `month` column.

Comment: It usually helps in getting a proper answer if you provide some of the attempts you made.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826441/return-average-of-counts-of-records-after-a-group-by-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use window functions, if your DBMS supports them – based on the use of `date_trunc` I assume you are using PostgreSQL. The reason why this works is that window functions are evaluated after GROUP BY has produced the group rows. So wrap the count in `AVG(...) OVER ()`, where the window is the whole set of results:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

month = func.date_trunc('month', Complaint.date)
records_count = func.count(ClientGroupRecord.id)
# Create a window of the whole set of results
records_avg = func.avg(records_count).over()

complained_clients = session.query(records_count.label('count'),
                                   records_avg.label('avg'),
                                   month.label('month')). \
    select_from(Friend). \
    join(Complaint, Complaint.friend == Friend.friend_id). \
    join(ClientGroup, Complaint.client_group == ClientGroup.client_group_id). \
    join(ClientGroupRecord, ClientGroup.client_group_id == ClientGroupRecord.client_group_id). \
    join(Client, Client.client_id == ClientGroupRecord.client_id). \
    filter(Friend.friend_id == friend_id). \
    group_by(month). \
    all()
```

Note that `Friend` is moved from the `query(...)` to being explicitly used as the left hand side of the first join with `Query.select_from()`. That removes the need to use `Friend.id` in the GROUP BY clause even though you are selecting only friends with a certain ID.

If you are not interested in the monthly counts at all, but want just the average, a more traditional [subquery approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826441/return-average-of-counts-of-records-after-a-group-by-statement) is just as good:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

month = func.date_trunc('month', Complaint.date)
records_count = func.count(ClientGroupRecord.id)

complained_clients = session.query(records_count.label('count')). \
    select_from(Friend). \
    join(Complaint, Complaint.friend == Friend.friend_id). \
    join(ClientGroup, Complaint.client_group == ClientGroup.client_group_id). \
    join(ClientGroupRecord, ClientGroup.client_group_id == ClientGroupRecord.client_group_id). \
    join(Client, Client.client_id == ClientGroupRecord.client_id). \
    filter(Friend.friend_id == friend_id). \
    group_by(month). \
    subquery()

result = session.query(func.avg(complained_clients.c.count)).scalar()
```

...or using the window approach:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

month = func.date_trunc('month', Complaint.date)
records_count = func.count(ClientGroupRecord.id)
# Create a window of the whole set of results
records_avg = func.avg(records_count).over()

# Windows are evaluated for each row, but here we have a single window spanning
# the entire result, so the use of DISTINCT collapses this to a single value.
# Knowing what the query does LIMIT 1 / FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY would work as well.
result = session.query(records_avg.label('avg')). \
    select_from(Friend). \
    join(Complaint, Complaint.friend == Friend.friend_id). \
    join(ClientGroup, Complaint.client_group == ClientGroup.client_group_id). \
    join(ClientGroupRecord, ClientGroup.client_group_id == ClientGroupRecord.client_group_id). \
    join(Client, Client.client_id == ClientGroupRecord.client_id). \
    filter(Friend.friend_id == friend_id). \
    group_by(month). \
    distinct(). \
    scalar()
```